# PHP - date() vs. date.timezone / date_default_timezone_set()

Tags: php, date, warnings, php-ini

I've just got a new computer, and I've been setting up PHP/MySQL/databases etc... I think I'm just about there, except it's thrown this curveball. My login script was working fine, but now it's spitting the following warning (which messes up the JSON).

> **Warning**:  date() [function.date]:
>   It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are
>   *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Antarctica/Macquarie'
>   for 'EST/10.0/no DST' instead in **.../php/login.php** on line
>   **47**

My code obviously uses `date()` and is working in the live version and on the old machine. I get two warnings for the following two lines of code:

```
$date = date("ymd");

$this_year = date("y");
```

My research (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php)) suggests that the behaviour of these functions depends on php.ini .

So should I change php.ini on the new machine, or am I using some kind of deprecated method, and should I ditch `date()` altogether?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, all. Using date_default_timezone_set('...') worked like a charm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to change the php.ini file if you use [`date_default_timezone_set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php). Just set it to the timezone you will be working in.

Something like this should go in a config file or on the page where you're working with dates (if it is only one page):

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not an exception, it's a warning that is probably popping up now because your error reporting settings on the new machine are different from the old one.

I would suggest to follow the suggestion in the warning, and use [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set a time-zone in the scripts where you need it.

Answer (score 4):

First, you are although it may know, this solves the problem.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Your/Timezone');
```

If you want to configure in php.ini, modify below

```
[Date]
; ...
; ...
date.timezone = Your/Timezone
```

Answer (score 4):

You do not have to change the php.ini.

However, if you have a timezone which you will use for most of your your php files adding the following line to your php.ini should do the trick.

```
date.timezone = "Your/Timezone"
```

In my case I added the following line to php.ini. Personally, I prefer to keep all our servers at UTC timezone.

```
date.timezone = "UTC"
```