# Laravel timezone settings not taking effect

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime, timezone

I am working on a Laravel application that has the timezone set to **UTC** in the `config/app.php` and `config/database.php` files, and the timezone on the MySQL server is set to **America/Denver** and cannot be changed there because we have multiple apps using that server.

The problem is, when saving a new model with timestamps, the `created_at`/`updated_at` are set in the **America/Denver** timezone, when I need them to use the **UTC** timezone. I have played around quite a bit and have tried the following with no luck:

Made sure that the timezone settings were not incorrectly cached as suggested [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14428) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44776169/5552707):

```
$ php artisan cache:clear    
$ php artisan view:clear
$ php artisan config:cache
```

Set my PHP script timezone to **UTC** as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308315/php-date-vs-date-timezone-date-default-timezone-set) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37722681/how-to-set-laravel-carbon-timezone-for-timestamps/37722990) and outlined [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC')
```

Set the MySQL session timezone to **UTC** as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428563/set-timezone-in-php-and-mysql) and outlined [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html):

```
DB::statement("SET time_zone='UTC';")
DB::select('SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;')
```

I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Alright...

It appears that my dates are indeed stored in **UTC** but are *displayed* in local time... I was not expecting this behavior as I come from a SQL Server background and have never encountered this before. I tested that this is in fact the case by creating a few model records, then selecting them back out using **UTC**, and received the correct records. Seems to be good to go, just a bit confusing. If you have an explanation as to why MySQL will store datetimes in UTC but displays them in the local server time, that would be helpful!

Thanks!